# Best way to fetch an Enum class name itself as String

Tags: java

I have an enum.

public enum Market {
A,
B,
C;
}

I want to get the class name. So getEnumClassName() returns the String "Market".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Java classes have the [`getSimpleName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName()) method, which returns the name of the class, or enum, whichever it may be.  So to get the name of the `Market` enum as a string you could use:

```java
Market.class.getSimpleName()
```

Or, if you want `Market` to have a method `getEnumClassName()` that returns the name as you describe, you could write it like so:

```java
public enum Market {
    A,
    B,
    C;

    public static String getEnumClassName() {
        return Market.class.getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or call `getClass().getSimpleName()` on any of the enum's values.

Comment: @StephenC Sure, that works, too.  But the class name is not dependent on the enum value.

Comment: @StephenC Are you _certain_ of that? They're technically subclasses.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I can confirm after a quick empirical test that Stephen's method does return the class name of the enum, not the name of the value.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I think it depends if you subclass them (e.g. `A {...}`).

Comment: @StephenC You can specify a body on the constant, and it acts as anonymous subclass: https://ideone.com/XRA5uO

Comment: Oh ... err ... umm ... I didn't know that.   In that case, Chrylis is right.  (I was also checking the JLS, and it says that an enum value with a class body is a subclass.  It makes sense.)

Comment: @StephenC I knew I've gone `jd`-diving and seen more dollar signs than a cable-TV bill.

Answer (score 1):

Enum values have [getDeclaringClass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass()) method which returns consistent value of the declaring class, even if the enum values themselves are anonymous classes and may have different values of `getClass().getSimpleName()`.

So a declaration of `getEnumClassName()` does not need to include `Market` and you could cut/paste this method to different enum classes as is:

```
public enum Market {
    A,
    B,
    C;
    public static String getEnumClassName() {
        return values()[0].getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```